# `DataFrame.add` creates missing value in spite of using fill_value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm adding two DataFrames with mismatched columns/indexes. But in spite of using `fill_values` parameter I'm getting some unexpected missing value in the result. I'm new to Python, so if any body can guide me to understand what is happening here, that will be really helpful. Here is my code (I'm using Anaconda3):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape((2,2)),
        index=list('ab'), columns=list('xy'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(3).reshape((3,1)),
        index=list('abc'), columns=list('y'))
print(df1.add(df2, fill_value=0))
     x    y
a  0.0  1.0
b  2.0  4.0
c  NaN  2.0
print(df2.add(df1, fill_value=0))
     x    y
a  0.0  1.0
b  2.0  4.0
c  NaN  2.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) note,

> Equivalent to dataframe + other, but with support to substitute a
>   fill_value for missing data in **one of** the inputs.

You get NaN because (c, X) doesn't exist in either DataFrame, and this operation is taking the union of (row, column) pairs.

A workaround would just be

```
df2.add(df1, fill_value=0.).fillna(value=0.)
```